# How to set a time range on the X axis and date range in the Y axis with colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a code, which shows a heatmap of the data in the CSV file.
The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data= pd.read_csv("data.csv" , sep=';', header=0, 
index_col='Date')
fig=plt.imshow(data, cmap='YlOrBr', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Time (UTC)")
plt.ylabel("Date")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The dataset is as follows:

[image]

The time range varies from 00:00 till 23:50 with steps of 10 minutes. 
I want the x axis to show the time from 00:00 till 23:50 in steps per hour.

The index is set as date. The date range is from 29-Oct-2017 till 24-Mar-2018. 
I want the Y axis to show the date range in steps of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `stack` columns, then `groupby` month and hour and then `unstack` it back (I'm taking `mean` values here when aggregating, but you can change to `sum` or whatever aggregation should be done there):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,
                  columns=pd.date_range('00:00', '23:50', freq='10min'),
                  index=pd.date_range('2017-10-29', '2018-03-24'))
df[df.columns] = np.random.randint(0, 100, df.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(10,6))
ax[0].imshow(df, cmap='YlOrBr')

ix = df.stack().index
l1 = ix.get_level_values(0).month
l2 = ix.get_level_values(1).hour

df2 = df.stack().groupby([l1,l2], sort=False).mean().unstack(1)

ax[1].imshow(df2, cmap='YlOrBr')
```

Output (original DataFrame above, processed below):

[image: output]

**Update:**

If the goal is just to put monthly and hourly labels on the same plot, please see below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,
                  columns=pd.date_range('00:00', '23:50', freq='10min').astype(str),
                  index=pd.date_range('2017-10-29', '2018-03-24').astype(str))

df[df.columns] = np.random.randn(*(df.shape))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,6))

l1 = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month
l2 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).hour
x = pd.Series(l2).drop_duplicates()
y = pd.Series(l1).drop_duplicates()

ax.imshow(df, cmap='YlOrBr')

ax.set_xticks(x.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)

ax.set_yticks(y.index)
ax.set_yticklabels(y)
```

Output:

[image: output(2)]

Comment: isn't there an more easy option>

Comment: Is there any step that seems unnecessary to you? You do have to create month-hour groups and calculate mean/sum on each group, right? And everything before `ix = ...` is basically just generating a sample DataFrame, so you won't need that in your code since you already have your DataFrame, so 4 simple lines is all there is to it

Comment: I get an error saying; 'index; object has no attribute 'month'

Comment: Maybe your index is not DatetimeIndex, try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%y')` to convert it

Comment: Or actually try with `l1 = pd.to_datetime(ix.get_level_values(0), format='%d-%m-%y').month` and `l2 = pd.to_datetime(ix.get_level_values(1), format='%H:%M')` (this will convert both dates and hours, which is what we need if you have them stored as strings)

Comment: I get your point, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Now he sorts the dates per month and values them per month (I only get 5 values in the Y-axis). I Only want the Yticks and Xticks to be sorter per month and per hour.

Comment: I think maybe I didn't get your question right, please see "Update" section of my answer. Is that what you were after?